# Entity Framework: many-to-many relationship referencing same entity type without join entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am learning .NET and Entity Framework and am trying to create a many-to-many relationship in EF where the relationship (actually two different relationships) is with the same type of entity.

Each Educational Unit can have a list of equivalent educational units.
Each Educational Unit can have a list of prerequisite Educational units.

Here are the classes:

```
public class EducationalUnit : IAutoAssignable
{
    public Guid Id { get; init; }
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public bool HasAutoAssign {get; set;}
    public bool IsTopLevel {get; set;}
    public int OrderInParent {get; set;}
    public double Duration {get; set;}
    public List<EducationalUnit>? Prerequisites {get; set;}
    public List<EducationalUnit>? Equivalents {get; set;}
    public List<Enrollment>? Enrollments {get; set;}
    public List<Competency>? Competencies {get; set;}
    public List<Tag>? Tags {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
    public string AssignmentLogicString {get; set;}
    public User CreatedBy {get; set;}
    public User Owner {get; set;}
}
```

I am struggling to find a way how to implement this in EF. Is the approach here to create two join entities for these relationships (like below) and have two join tables in the DB? is there a best practice for these types of relationships?

```
public class Equivalent
{
    public EducationalUnit EducationalUnitOne {get; set;}
    public EducationalUnit EducationalUnitTwo {get; set;}
}

public class Prerequisite
{
    public EducationalUnit MainEduationalUnit {get; set;}
    public EducationalUnit PrerequisiteEducationalUnit {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From EF Core 7, shadow property navigation is supported. You can configure the navigation like :

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<EducationalUnit>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Prerequisites)
        .WithMany("Mains");

    var manyMany = modelBuilder.Entity<EducationalUnit>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Equivalents)
        .WithMany("Equivalents1");
}
```

---

In EF Core 6/5, shadow navigation property isn't supported. You need to define a CLR property for navigation property like :

```cs
public class EducationalUnit
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    ...

    public List<EducationalUnit>? Prerequisites { get; set; }
    public List<EducationalUnit>? NeededTo { get; set; }

    public List<EducationalUnit>? Equivalents { get; set; }
    public List<EducationalUnit>? Equivalents1 { get; set; }
}
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<EducationalUnit>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Prerequisites)
        .WithMany(u => u.NeededTo);

    modelBuilder.Entity<EducationalUnit>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Equivalents)
        .WithMany(u => u.Equivalents1);
}
```