# How to set the many to many relationship without an entity for the join table in Entity Framework Core with fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I would like to configure a many-to-many relationship with Fluent API,  but I don't want to create a join entity, and am trying to follow the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many

And I have this question too: [Entity Framework: many-to-many relationship referencing same entity type without join entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74337460/entity-framework-many-to-many-relationship-referencing-same-entity-type-without)

But I am not able to configure my case. I am not using name conventions, so perhaps it is the reason I don't understand how to set them

This is my entity:

```cs
public class Person
{
    long Id;
    string Name;

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _contactPersons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Person> ContactPersons => _contactPersons;

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _representedPersons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Person> RepresentedPersons => _representedPersons;
}
```

The idea is that one person can have many contact persons, persons that represent to one person and a person can represent many persons.

My table in the database base is this:

```
PersonsAndContacts(IDPerson, IDContactPerson)
```

According to the documentation, I am trying to configure the relationship in this way:

```cs
paramPersonafiguracion.HasKey(o => o.Id);

paramPersonafiguracion.Property<long>(o => o.Id)
    .HasColumnName("IDPerson")
    .HasColumnType("bigint")
    .IsRequired();

paramPersonfiguracion
    .HasMany(x => x.ContactPersosns)
    .WithMany(x => x.RepresentedPersons)
    .UsingEntity(
        l => l.HasOne(nameof(Person)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("IDPerson"),
        r => r.HasOne(nameof(Person)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("IDContactPerson"));
```

But when I try to run a query, I get this exception:

> The entity type 'Person (Dictionary<string, object>)' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

But I have defined that the primary key is the Id property.

So how could I configure the relationship with fluent API?

Thanks.

Comment: The error complains about `The entity type 'Person (Dictionary<string, object>)`. That's not what's shown in the question. What are the *real* types involved? Please post a reproducible example. Personally I'd expect the read-only properties and types to cause problems.

Comment: The example should include the tables too. `IDPerson` definitely doesn't follow naming conventions

Comment: `Id` in your entity `Person` isn't a property - it's a field - but it **needs to be** a full property `public long Id { get; set; }`